# How to INSERT INTO a MySQL database using a HTML Select

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I'm not sure why my code is not working, i have moderate knowledge of HTML but little to know knowledge of PHP or MySQL databases.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance

```
<body>
<form method="POST" action=''>
<input type="submit" name="button1"  value="My Button">
</form>
<br />
<br />
<select name="DayOption">
<option value="1"<?php $test== "8"; ?>>8</option>
<option value="2"<?php $test== "9"; ?>>9</option>
</select>
<?php
$servername = "db568845851.db.1and1.com";
$username = "dbo568845851";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db568845851";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST['button1']))
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Rota1 (DayAndTime, FirstEmployeeID, SecondEmployeeID, ThirdEmployeeID) VALUES ('".$test."', '2', '2', '2')";
}


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>


</body>
```

Comment: Also - what do you mean by "code is not working"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
<form method="POST" action='#'>
<input type="submit" name="button1"  value="My Button">
<select name="DayOption">
<option value="1">8</option>
<option value="2">9</option>
</select>
</form>
```

and php variable with selected option

```
$dayoption = $_POST['DayOption'];
```

and in insert sql

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Rota1 (DayAndTime, FirstEmployeeID, SecondEmployeeID, ThirdEmployeeID) VALUES ('$dayoption', '2', '2', '2')";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, now working, you have saved my entire university grade with this answer!